# How to change default text alignment of a pie chart

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport

I am using a pie chart in my application, so i created a custom pie chart without any third party api. The default alignment of the pie chart text is coming as in center.
How to change the position of the text to move little up.
[image: I need to create like this]

But till now i have created this
[image]

```
textPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            textPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            textPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
            textPaint.setTypeface(face);
```

By this i am doing customization in Custom Pie Chart but it is not taking margin or padding.
Pie Chart xml

```
<com.example.app.CustomPieChart
        android:id="@+id/piechart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/img_two"
        ProgressWheel:textColor="#222222"
        ProgressWheel:textSize="60sp"
        ProgressWheel:rimColor="#44000000"
        ProgressWheel:barLength="60dp"
        ProgressWheel:barColor="#339BB9"
        ProgressWheel:barWidth="5dp"
        ProgressWheel:rimWidth="5dp"
        ProgressWheel:spinSpeed="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="70dp" />
```

Comment: To get help you should post some snippets of your code.

Comment: u can use margin and padding? :)

Comment: This is a default text coming with pie chart, so it is not taking any margin or padding.